# Put dict/json to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following input:

```
{'1LsquDfKDtz1uFz7txAVixkgFc82PHwqqp': {"balance": 0}, '1FBGyQnLZrfwVZRdYNxbrqnKukm9trH5Ka': {"balance": 0}, '1DSBqLVtDFgMypdo2yC77C5LZuTCHZS7St': {"balance": 34},
...
```

That I would like to put in a a dataframe. But I run the code:

```
p = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(input)
```

I got the error:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Expected output in xlsx:

```
                          addresse     balance
'1LsquDfKDtz1uFz7txAVixkgFc82PHwqqp'          0
'1FBGyQnLZrfwVZRdYNxbrqnKukm9trH5Ka'          0
'1DSBqLVtDFgMypdo2yC77C5LZuTCHZS7St'         34
```

Any contribution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter `orient='index'` to  [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html), then create index name by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and last convert index to column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
d = {'1LsquDfKDtz1uFz7txAVixkgFc82PHwqqp': {"balance": 0}, 
     '1FBGyQnLZrfwVZRdYNxbrqnKukm9trH5Ka': {"balance": 0}, 
     '1DSBqLVtDFgMypdo2yC77C5LZuTCHZS7St': {"balance": 34}}
```

---

```
p = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').rename_axis('addresse').reset_index()
print (p)
                             addresse  balance
0  1DSBqLVtDFgMypdo2yC77C5LZuTCHZS7St       34
1  1FBGyQnLZrfwVZRdYNxbrqnKukm9trH5Ka        0
2  1LsquDfKDtz1uFz7txAVixkgFc82PHwqqp        0
```

Another idea is use list comprehension and prepend new key to list of dictionaries, last pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
p = pd.DataFrame([dict(**{'addresse':k}, **v) for k, v in d.items()])
print (p)
                             addresse  balance
0  1LsquDfKDtz1uFz7txAVixkgFc82PHwqqp        0
1  1FBGyQnLZrfwVZRdYNxbrqnKukm9trH5Ka        0
2  1DSBqLVtDFgMypdo2yC77C5LZuTCHZS7St       34
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative code:

Using `.from_dict()`, `.stack()`, `.unstack()` and `.reset_index()`. Modified the code posted in the question.

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd

# Create dictionary
d = {'1LsquDfKDtz1uFz7txAVixkgFc82PHwqqp': {"balance": 0}, 
     '1FBGyQnLZrfwVZRdYNxbrqnKukm9trH5Ka': {"balance": 0}, 
     '1DSBqLVtDFgMypdo2yC77C5LZuTCHZS7St': {"balance": 34}
    }

# Create DataFrame from dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d).stack().unstack(0).reset_index()

# Rename columns
df.columns = ['address', 'balance']
```

Output

```
print(df)

                              address  balance
0  1LsquDfKDtz1uFz7txAVixkgFc82PHwqqp        0
1  1FBGyQnLZrfwVZRdYNxbrqnKukm9trH5Ka        0
2  1DSBqLVtDFgMypdo2yC77C5LZuTCHZS7St       34
```